# Deleted images still being shown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For some reason, my website still showing images that were already deleted from the specified folder and I have no idea why that's happening and how to solve that.

**Process:** When the button to delete all admins is pressed, it calls a PHP function that truncate the tables administration, adminimg and login, delete all images from a folder related to id's on table administration with unlink(), and create a registry on administration table with id=1(auto_increment) and name="abc".

**Problem:** I have a jQuery function that display a specific admin information on textboxes, verify the value in the textbox for the adminID, and display the image associated to that id. After executing the process above, when i call the jQuery function, it display correctly the id=1 and name="abc" but shows the deleted image associated to the admin with id=1 before truncate the tables.

**jQuery function** (if necessary)

```
$(".btneditadmin").click( e =>{
  let textvalues = displayDataAdmin(e);
  let id = $("input[name*='idadmin']");
  let name = $("input[name*='nameadmin']");

  id.val(textvalues[0]);
  nome.val(textvalues[1]);

  var img_url = 'Images/Administration/admin'+$("#idadmin").val()+'.jpg';
  $("#admin-image").attr('src',img_url);
});

function displayDataAdmin(e) {
  let id = 0;
  const td = $("#tbody tr td");
  let textvalues = [];

  for (const value of td){
      if(value.dataset.id == e.target.dataset.id){
         textvalues[id++] = value.textContent;
      }
  }
  return textvalues;
}
```

Comment: deleting an image from a server won't clear the one stored in your browsers cache

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Unless the Chrome dev tool doesn't work im sure im refreshing the page with the cache disabled so i doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Please at least clear the browser cache ONCE to see the effect. (not just rely on the cache disabled option in chrome dev tool). Let us know the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that image isn't there anymore then it's caching issue and something like this would take care of it

```
let img_url = 'Images/Administration/admin'+$("#idadmin").val()+'.jpg';
img_url += '?' + new Date().getTime() ; // cache killer
$("#admin-image").attr('src', img_url);
```

However, you're calling that function no matter what so I would suggest a onload/error check

```
​$('#admin-image').load(function(){ // when loaded successfully
   console.log('success');  
}).error(function(){  // when theres an error
   $(this).remove() 
    // or you could replace it with a default image  
   $(this).attr('src', '/images/default.jpg');
});​​​​​
```